# <noinclude>category:example</noinclude> in template, undesirably wraps content in <pre> tag

Tags: php, html, css, mediawiki, wiki

In MediaWiki 1.32.0 in Hebrew, if one creates a template named `רקע_אפור` ("Grey background") with the following content:

```
<span style="background: grey">{{{1}}}</span>
<noinclude>[[קטגוריה:דוגמה]]</noinclude>
```

Having `<noinclude>` before `[[קטגוריה:דוגמה]]`, makes passages containing the **template call** to be wrapped inside a `<pre>` tag with a line break; for example:

### Current state

#### Code

```
מופע_1 {{תבנית:רקע_אפור|מופע_2}} מופע_3
```

#### Output

> מופע_1
>
> `מופע_2`
>
> מופע_3

### Desired state

#### Code

```
מופע_1 {{תבנית:רקע_אפור|מופע_2}} מופע_3
```

#### Output

> מופע_1 `מופע_2` מופע_3

Why is the `<pre>` tag and line break get created happening and how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<span style="background: grey">{{{1}}}</span><noinclude>
[[קטגוריה:דוגמה]]
</noinclude>
```

The problem is that in your original code, there's a newline after `</span>`, so:

```
מופע_1 {{תבנית:רקע_אפור|מופע_2}} מופע_3
```

is expanded to:

```
מופע_1 <span style="background: grey">מופע_2</span>
 מופע_3
```

which causes the `pre` to happen.

Comment: I don't understand why, but it seems to work fine (I don't understand why because I already tried to put everything in one line).